# Generating GameObject in front of player infinitely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I have a 'player' 3D Object and a 'circle' 3D Object. The player can move towards the circles one by one already.

I need the circles to generate randomly in front of the player when spacebar is pressed, e.g spacebar pressed then one circle generated, spacebar pressed again then another circle generated and so on.

As in randomly generated, it needs to spawn on the radius of the existing circle, e.g 2 units away from the circle anywhere in front that is not behind (180 degree)

All this text may make the question seem complicated but all I really need is another circle created in front of the existing one.

It would also be helpful if you could use some sort of random rotation of the player in order to generate in front of the player.

This is my code so far, feel free to completely wipe my original code in the answer:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector3 playerPos;
    public GameObject yourObject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        playerPos = playerPos.transform.position;
        Instantiate(yourObject, new Vector3(playerPos.transform.position.x +  5, playerPos.transform.position.y, playerPos.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Errr, your code only instantiates one object exactly 5 units in front of the playerPos. Did you actually make an attempt to write code/research code for what you're looking for?

Comment: Here are a few links that should help you out:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: Something that may help readers of the question is a diagram, to explain what you want to happen - because you're right, the wording of your question doesn't make it immediately clear how you want new circles to be arranged.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many units, the code says 5 and my example was 2. That doesn't make a difference. @Alox

Comment: I'm aware that your code says 5, thats why I said what your code was doing. I then referred two links which should give you ample information to solve your problem, given that you put some effort into it.

Comment: I just added a diagram, I hope that helps... @Serlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rotate your player around your Up Vector between your max and min angle then use your distance and direction to find the new position
for the random angle part you can generate a random number with
`RandomAngle=Random.Range(MinAngle,MaxAngle);`
then use it with 
 
`Quaternion.AngleAxis(RandomAngle, playerUpVector)`

to rotate it around your players Upvector, I dont know what you used for your Up vector but normally it is  `Vector3.up`
then multiply it by your players direction(`playerLocalDirection`) that which normally is `Vector3.forward`

```
Vector3 newPos= myPos + Quaternion.AngleAxis(RandomAngle, playerUpVector) * playerLocalDirection * DistanceFromPlayer;
```

Comment: But what is the enemyPos supposed to be?

Comment: it is the position that you should use to instantiate your new object, name it whatever you want